# Check the null or empty record condition

Tags: sql, list, if-statement, jdbc

I wanted to know if I did this code well, to check if the coding of a record is null or empty, getTraduction (), if I did something wrong, just let me know where I went wrong.
because I would like to have even null records printed

```
public void getTraduttoreIt_CLASS_HDR_NLS() throws Exception {
        List<ClassHdrNls> db2 = getListCLASS_HDR_NLS();
        List<DizioPt> sqlServer = getListDizioPt();
        BufferedWriter scrivi = new BufferedWriter(
                new FileWriter("C:/Users/francesco/Desktop/Table_ClassHdrNls_Sez3.txt"));
        for (int i = 0; i < db2.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < sqlServer.size(); j++) {
                if (db2.get(i).getNlsClassName().equals(sqlServer.get(j).getKeyword())) {
                    System.out.println("-------------------FILE N°3---------------------------");
                    System.out.println("-------------------ITALIANO---------------------------");
                    System.out.println("CLASS_NAME: " + db2.get(i).getClassName());
                    scrivi.newLine();
                    scrivi.write("CLASS_NAME: ");
                    scrivi.write(db2.get(i).getClassName());
                    scrivi.newLine();
                    System.out.println("NLS_CLASS_NAME: " + db2.get(i).getNlsClassName());
                    scrivi.write("NLS_CLASS_NAME: ");
                    scrivi.write(db2.get(i).getNlsClassName());
                    scrivi.newLine();
                    System.out.println("NLS_PL_CLASS_NAME: " + db2.get(i).getNlsPlClassName());
                    scrivi.write("NLS_PL_CLASS_NAME: ");
                    scrivi.write(db2.get(i).getNlsPlClassName());
                    scrivi.newLine();
                    System.out.println("KEYWORD: " + sqlServer.get(j).getKeyword());
                    scrivi.write("KEYWORD: ");
                    scrivi.write(sqlServer.get(j).getKeyword());
                    scrivi.newLine();
                    System.out.println("LINGUA ITALIANO: " + db2.get(i).getLanguage() + " ***");
                    scrivi.write("LINGUA ITALIANO: ");
                    scrivi.write(db2.get(i).getLanguage() + " ***");
                    scrivi.newLine();

                    // Faccio un controllo se il valore è diverso da null o il record è vuoto
                    if (sqlServer.get(j).getTraduzione() == null || sqlServer.get(j).getTraduzione().isEmpty()) {
                        System.out.println("TRADUZIONE: ***********");
                        scrivi.write("TRADUZIONE: ");
                        scrivi.write("*******************");
                        scrivi.newLine();
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("TRADUZIONE: " + sqlServer.get(j).getTraduzione());
                        scrivi.write("TRADUZIONE: ");
                        scrivi.write(sqlServer.get(j).getTraduzione());
                        scrivi.newLine();
                    }

                    System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------");
                    scrivi.flush();
                }
            }

        }
        scrivi.close();
    }
```

Output:
Print only non-null and non-empty records.

I also want to print null records

Answer (score 0):

this line:

```
 if (db2.get(i).getNlsClassName().equals(sqlServer.get(j).getKeyword()))
```

could be why you are not printing null values, since it forces printing only after there is a match.

You should inspect your data (print all of it) to see what you are getting.
If you are finding null values, then that means printing inside the if condition is what's stopping you from seeing the null values get printed.